# @Converter(autoApply = true) not working in different package

Tags: spring-boot, jpa, spring-data-jpa, spring-data

This is under package: `com.a.b`

```java
package com.a.b;
@Converter(autoApply = true)
public class DateConverter implements AttributeConverter<Date, String> {
}
```

application start class under package: `com.a.c`

```
package com.a.c;
public class Application {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);
    }
}
```

in differnet package, `autoApply = true` not working, except custom `LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean`. Are there other solutions

Comment: Ummm... not putting `DateConverter` in an unrelated package? Alternatively, try putting `@SpringBootApplication(scanBasePackages = {"com.a.b", "com.a.c"})` on top of `Application`

Comment: @crizzis still not working.

Comment: stupid question why is it not in the package hierarchy of your spring boot application?

Comment: @SimonMartinelli Because I need a universal tool ! i fix it !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to use `@EntityScan`. I assume that your entities are in `com.a.c`. If this is not the case you have to set the correct package:

```
package com.a.c;

@SpringBootApplication
@EntityScan(basePackages = {"com.a.c", "com.a.b"})
public class Application {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);
    }
}
```

Comment: It's working, and `@AutoConfigurationPackage(basePackages = {"com.a.c", "com.a.b"})
` working too. thank you!